# Perl can't install Net::SSL

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssl

In order to install RT4.2, I tried to install Net::SSL, but without success. This is the output: (Ubuntu Server12.04, perl 5.14.2)

When I choice N selection that don't test connection, also can't success.

```
sudo cpan install Net::SSL
[sudo] password for hengaini: 
Going to read '/home/hengaini/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 20 Feb 2014 09:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Net::SSL'
Running make for N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/hengaini/.cpan/sources/authors/id/N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz

The test suite can attempt to connect to public servers to ensure that the
code is working properly. If you are behind a strict firewall or have no
network connectivity, these tests may fail (through no fault of the code).
Do you want to run the live tests (y/N)? [N] y
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lssl32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lssleay32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -leay32
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Crypt::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/X509.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/X509.pm
cp lib/Net/SSL.pm blib/lib/Net/SSL.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm
cp SSLeay.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  SSLeay.xs > SSLeay.xsc && mv SSLeay.xsc SSLeay.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"0.64\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.64\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.14/CORE"   SSLeay.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" cc  -shared -O2 -g -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector SSLeay.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so    \
       -lz -lssl -lcrypto   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- SSLeay.bs blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.bs 644
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::SSLeay.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Net::SSL.3pm
  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-basic.t .... ok     
t/01-connect.t .. 1/8 
#   Failed test 'Net::SSL->new'
#   at t/01-connect.t line 28.
# Connect failed: connect: &#25298;&#32477;&#36830;&#25509;; &#25298;&#32477;&#36830;&#25509; at t/01-connect.t line 11.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 8.
t/01-connect.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/8 subtests 
    (less 7 skipped subtests: 0 okay)
t/02-live.t ..... # Reading configuration from 'test.config' on linux
# network_tests : 1
t/02-live.t ..... 1/? # [RT #73755] Cheat by disabling LWP::UserAgent host verification
t/02-live.t ..... ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01-connect.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 8 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=3, Tests=28,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.00 sys +  0.53 cusr  0.30 csys =  0.86 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/3 test programs. 1/28 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] &#38169;&#35823; 255
  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.64.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Comment: You can use `apt-get` to install Perl modules also. `apt-cache search net-ssl` to find out the package name.

Comment: What is the output without run the live tests?

Answer (score 2):

A very old question, but I was stuck searching for this as well

Instead of attempting to install Perl's SSL modules with CPAN, you should, as @TLP stated in their comment on the original question, use the Ubuntu package manager

```
apt-cache search net-ssl
```

Will give a list of packages. For example:

```
apt install libnet-ssleay-perl
apt install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```

These worked for me on Perl v5.20 and v5.30. You will have to search to see which libraries work for yours using `apt-cache search`

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, I hope you are using a [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) or [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) based environment, and since you have at least bothered to install `cpan` rather than rely on the default packages.

So you seem to missing the libraries and headers for SSL on your system, fix this by:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

And if you haven'y already, look into setting up your environment with one of the methods as linked above and look into [cpanminus](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) as well for a **very** useful tool that compliments either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that testing after build was not successful and error is occurred in this file t/01-connect.t line 11.

```
eval {
    $sock = Net::SSL->new(
        PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',
        PeerPort => 443,
        Timeout  => 3,
    );
};
```

I can assume that some process is already listening on 127.0.0.1 443 port. Try to stop it and reinstall it again in the way you would like. Tests should always be passed.